# Proccess.Start can not find the path with \\ in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open a pdf file that is located on the network :

[image]

I call the file like this in c# (Sorry for sending my code as a picture because of `breakpoint` i have to)

But it can't find the path .Another thing that i should add is when i call the file outside the c# like this `\\127.0.0.1\dccfile\test\dcc1\1.pdf` it works .
[image]

Comment: Your path is wrong. don't replace `\\\` (Hint: use the magnifier icon to see the path)

Comment: @L.B i have done ,but same error

Comment: myaddress value (in the tooltip) only has single backslash at the beginning.

Comment: @GrantWinney let me check it maybe

Comment: @GrantWinney no same error

Comment: @L.B how can i use magnifier?

Comment: @MehrdadGhaffari see the tooltip in your picture. right to the *myaddress*

Comment: What happens if you do `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\127.0.0.1\dccfile\test\dcc1\1.pdf");` ?

Comment: @L.B thanks one of my slash before the ip is removed why?

Comment: @MehrdadGhaffari Now you know the problem, Debug your code step by step....

Comment: @reproduktor the main address is located in the static class if i use your solution i have to change all path in my application if the file address is changed

Comment: @L.B thank you it works i just add another ''\" after @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're looking at in the debugger tooltip is a C# literal, not a string. C# literals delimit strings with straight quotes `"` and escapes metacharacters with backslashes `\`. See the quotes at the start and end of the literal in the tooltip? They're not part of the string. Backslashes are C# metacharacters, to include one in a string you have to precede it with another backslash. The C# literal `"\\"` encodes a string containing a single backslash character. The first `\` you see in `"\\127.0.0...` is a metacharacter telling C# that the next character is a literal backslash, not a metacharacter. The code `"\\127.0.0.1\\DCCFile\\test\\dcc1\\1.pdf"` you see in the tooltip encodes the C# string `\127.0.0.1\DCCFile\test\dcc1\1.pdf` with no quotes and single backslashes.

Your problem is the value of `Configuration.AccountDetail.DCCFileAddress` needs to start with two backslashes and it does not.

Your code `pathString.Replace(@"\\", @"\")` will have no effect because there are no double backslashes in your string; the debugger is displaying the backslashes doubled so you know they are literal backslashes and not metacharacters.