# Parsing this kind of json stringified string "{\"value\":[\"18\"]}"

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I just can't figure this one out.
Tried already with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item) and I got a weird string as well.

How can I put out of value out of this stringified string?

```
"{\"value\":[\"18\"]}"
```

Edit@

This is where I stringify it:

```
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('cates', JSON.stringify(toSend));
```

and here is what output I get from model > props list

https://gyazo.com/b9a6f212345b854796af3d80e4169a23

@deserializing

```
        foreach (var item in data.cates)
        {
            var l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(item);
        }
```

Comment: why does your json have the \" character?. What happens if you replace that string before deserializing?. Try removing that from the string

Comment: You're going to need to supply more context. Where are you seeing that string? In a file? In C# source code? In the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: The escaping is because the JSON String is in a String. Therefore the quotes have to be escaped

Comment: @DourHighArch edited

Comment: Please show us the code you're actually using to deserialize it. You've only shown us how you're serializing it (however, you missed the important part of showing us what `toSend` it). Your attempt `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)` should be *Deserialize*, not *Serialize*

Comment: @Rob Done, sorry I missed that

Comment: Wait, are you seeing that string in the Visual Studio debugger? [The debugger shows metacharacters escaped with backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39428787/22437); the backslashes and quotes are not part of the string. Please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks as though your JSON has been double-serialized, i.e. an object was serialized to JSON, then that string was serialized **again**.  See [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559179/json-net-parser-seems-to-be-double-serializing-my-objects) for an example of how this mistake can easily be made with asp.net-web-api.

The best way to solve the problem is to not double-serialize the JSON to begin with.  If for whatever reason this cannot be fixed (because e.g. the double-serialized JSON is returned from some 3rd party service you cannot modify) you can always deserialize twice as well:

```
var json = @"""{\""value\"":[\""18\""]}""";

Console.WriteLine("JSON: ");
Console.WriteLine(json); // Prints "{\"value\":[\"18\"]}"

var intermediateJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(intermediateJson);

Console.WriteLine("Reserialized root: ");
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root)); // Prints {"value":["18"]}
Console.WriteLine("value:");
Console.WriteLine(root.value.First()); // Prints 18
```

Using, for a root object:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> value { get; set; }
}
```